# How to get permalink before the click

Tags: sql, wordpress

I have a dub... actually in a table I'm using this code to get the link custom posts title. It works as WP rewrite.
I would like to get permalink before to open the post.

This the code:

```
CONCAT('<a href="',posts_clases.guid,'" target="_self">',posts_clases.post_title,'</a>')
```

This the link in table: `https://example.com/?post_type=clases&p=110`

This is the page: `https://example.com/clases/empezar-respirando/`

Is possible to change "posts_clases.guid" and get the permalink on the table (before click)?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Finally I find best solution ... hope it will useful for someone.

Change this:

```
CONCAT('<a href="',posts_clases.guid,'" target="_self">',posts_clases.post_title,'</a>')
```

For this:

```
CONCAT('<a href="/clases/',posts_clases.post_name,'" target="_self">',posts_clases.post_title,'</a>') AS clases_title_with_link_to_post,
```